# Does the effect of the Boots of Speed magic item last for 9 rounds, or 11?

Tags: magic-items, pathfinder-2e, conditions, duration

On page 606 of the *Pathfinder* 2e *Core Rulebook*, the description of the *[Boots of Speed](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=414)* reads (emphasis mine):

> [...] You click the heels of the boots together and gain the **quickened condition** for one minute. [...]

Further reading of the description of the **[quickened condition](https://2e.aonprd.com/Conditions.aspx?ID=32)** on page 622 states:

> [...] Because quickened has its effect at the start of your turn, you don't immediately gain actions if you become quickened during your turn.

I understand all of this without issue. However, if the duration for the *Boots of Speed* is one minute (activating when the action to do so [clicking of the heels] takes place), then the duration would expire with only 9 rounds of actually being quickened.

Does the duration of the effect of the *boots of speed* delay or get stretched to allow for the 10 rounds that go by in 1 minute? Or does the player lose 1 round of being quickened?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## 9 rounds

Unless your group doesn't like the ruling, unfortunately, you "lose" one round of Quickened effects that you activate. Digging into Effects' [Duration](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=351)

> For an effect that lasts a number of rounds, the remaining duration **decreases by 1 at the start of each turn of the creature that created the effect.**

and [Step 1: Start your Turn](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=436)

> - If you created an effect lasting for a certain number of rounds, reduce the number of rounds remaining by 1.
>   [...]
>   **The last step** of starting your turn is always the same.
> - Regain your 3 actions and 1 reaction.

makes it pretty clear that you must reduce the duration of the Boots of Speed effect by one *before* you regain your Actions/Quickened Action.

Comment: "For an effect that lasts a number of rounds," - does it matter that the duration is specified as a time instead of a number of rounds?  Since the effect didn't start until the current round had started, I wouldn't think it would end until after 10 more turns have started.

Comment: I don't know of any further guidance on how to parse a 1 minute duration in combat. It is definitely enough wiggle room to say that it ends part-way through your turn or something, if a group prefers by-the-book over interpretation/preference when possible. Many encounters don't even last 10 rounds, but if your groups' experience is different, it may need to be formalized so everyone is on the same page about duration of minute(s).